How can I use the REST API created with Laravel in Next.js?
I have created a REST API with Laravel. How can I use this API in my Next.js application? Is it logical to use Next.js and Laravel together? Will I use it with the Next.js route handler? Will I use it with server actions? I am very confused.
I tried route handler and server action but I couldn't understand them. What is the correct way to do this?

I think laravel has a starter kit for a nextjs app with jetstream. Maybe you could use that for reference

Laravel has scaffolding for React as the frontend and Laravel as the backend. I'm not sure about Next.js. Are you having your backend and front as separate applications or one application? @Selçuk

My backend project is in a separate folder, and my frontend project is in a separate folder. I created them separately.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Based on your comment:

My backend project is in a separate folder, and my frontend project is in a separate folder. I created them separately

I guess you have to use a route handler and fetch the data from the laravel application. To do this:

You have to run the laravel application separately:
// for development you can run the application using the following command in terminal 
php artisan serve


Using a route handler you have to call the backend by using the laravel application's url and its routes. For example:
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/...', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'API-Key': process.env.DATA_API_KEY!,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ time: new Date().toISOString() }),
})



